# A Makefile to make some Cheese

Tags: javascript, node.js, makefile, mocha, babel.js

Excuse the pun in the title, the project this is for is called "[Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org)" (a type of cheese).

[Github](http://github.com/cheddar-lang/Cheddar)

---

I have recently been writing [a language](http://cheddar.vihan.org), in which I was using [grunt](http://gruntjs.com). Grunt was very slow for me, and had a lot more problems for me, so I switched my tasks over to [makefile](/questions/tagged/makefile). Most of my makefile knowledge is based off examples, googling, and brief tutorials, which is why I want to ask here on how it could be improved.

```
PREFIX=./node_modules/.bin
## Compiler
# The compiler to use for the ES7 -> ES5 transformation
JC=$(PREFIX)/babel
# Location of files
SRC=src/
OUT=dist/
# The flags to pass to the compiler
JCFLAGS=$(SRC) -d $(OUT)
# The binary files to copy
BIN=cli/cheddar
EXE=cheddar
BIN_MAKE=$(foreach BIN_FILE,$(BIN),chmod 755 $(SRC)$(BIN_FILE) && cp $(SRC)$(BIN_FILE) $(OUT)$(BIN_FILE)${\n});\
         ln -s $(OUT)cli/$(EXE) ./$(EXE)

## Tests
TESTRUNNER=$(PREFIX)/babel-node
COVERAGE=$(PREFIX)/babel-istanbul
TEST=$(PREFIX)/_mocha
TFLAGS=cover $(TEST)

## Rules
all: default

# The default task
# The **production** build
default: $(JC) $(SRC)
    $(JC) $(JCFLAGS) --minified
    $(BIN_MAKE)
# Development build task
# This builds and includes source maps
build: $(JC) $(SRC)
    $(JC) $(JCFLAGS) --sourceMaps="inline"
    $(BIN_MAKE)

# Runs install with default method
install: ./bin/install
    ./bin/install --method=path

# Performs testing, including coverage
# At the moment uses mocha for testing 
# and babel-istanbul for coverage
test: $(TESTRUNNER) $(COVERAGE) $(TEST)
    $(TESTRUNNER) $(COVERAGE) $(TFLAGS)
clean:
    rm -rf ./dist/
 .PHONY: test
```

Essentially what this does is it defined a couple of tasks:

- **default:** This is the default task. It runs babel, a compiler I need to compile the code from the `src/` directory to the output `dist/` directory.  It passes the `--minified` flag because this is a production build so we don't want big unminified code.
  *Following* is `BIN_MAKE`. This runs code to `chmod 755` a list of binary files stored in the `BIN` variable. It then moves these files from the source dir `src/` to the destination/output dir `dist/`.

  Lastly, it symlinks the executable to start the program from deep within the `dist/` directory to the root for easy-access.
- **build::** This is a development build. It compiled the same **as above**, but instead of `--minify` passes a `--sourceMap` arg to create source maps
- **install:** This runs an install script to install the application into the user's computer. The script's contents is located in an external file.
- **test:** This runs a file to simply test the application. If you know Mocha or Istanbul, this just runs that. `_mocha` and `babel-istanbul` are in variables as they are located in `./node_modules/.bin/`.
- **clean:** This removes the dist/ dir which is the location of the output of the build.

Comment: Do you have some superfluous indentation before `.PHONY`?

Comment: @200_success Yes, it appears I do :/ The tutorial I was looking at had it. Must of been a typo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In makefiles you can have spacing around equals signs, making the code slightly easier to read. For example `PREFIX = ./node_modules/.bin`.
- `UPPER_CASE` variables are generally used for things that the end user might want to change when running, while `lower_case` is for internal use variables. The user is presumably not supposed to change for example the source directory, so `SRC` should really be `src`.
- Single-use internal variables like `BIN` make the code harder to read for no tangible benefit. Introduce a variable when you need to reuse the value.
- Any target which has a name that doesn't correspond to an actual file created by that target should IMO be marked as `.PHONY` (because it is).
- Conversely, targets which *do* generate result files from their dependencies *should* be named for the files they generate, so that the Magic of Make™ can kick in and skip targets when they are up to date.
- `BIN_MAKE` would be much easier to understand as either commands in a target or as a separate script.
- The default target of a Makefile is the first one, [by definition](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html). That makes it redundant to have *two* phony targets (`all` and `default`) to do the default thing.
- Some more space between the targets would be nice.
- The comments are a bit verbose. Most of the time I find it's possible to make the code understandable enough (especially by naming things carefully) that comments become redundant.
- There should be an end user variable for each command you run that's assumed to be on the `PATH`, for example `CP = /bin/cp`. This may be considered overkill, especially for common tools, but it allows people who have tools off the `PATH` (for example after building it themselves) to run your Makefile without modifying it. A common use case (just like with RVM or Virtualenv) is if you want to test your Makefile with a tool version not installed on your base system.

  - `RM` is an [implicit variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) at least in GNU Make for just this purpose.